# Out"date"d/unused tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Sorry for the pun, but there's an outdated tag, [jewish-date-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-date-series). Since we're not using meta-tags (and since the series seems to have stopped), it probably ought to be done away with.

Comment: I've informed the author of the [tag:jewish-date-series]-tagged questions of the existence of this question in a comment at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4518.

Comment: I agree, as it never took off.