# Does "17 of Tammuz occurrences" fall under the same problem as the Jewish-Date series?

Tags: discussion

There's an [old post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3380/9682) on here about the [jewish-date-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-date-series), talking about how they're all off-topic as Jews not Judaism and spitballing ideas about reviving or if it's viable.

One particular question, [17 of Tammuz occurrences](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1998/9682), seems different from the others (besides that it's not a Teves question nor posted by Gershon Gold). On the one hand, the OP never specified what sorts of events he's looking for in an answer, and the answers list the signing of the Declaration of Independence (not even Jewish) and the yahrtzeit of Rav Yaakov Weinberg zt"l (with all due reverence to the Rav, still not on-topic). On the other hand, the OP himself posted an answer quoting the Mishnah in Ta'anis, which is certainly on-topic.

Should this question be closed like the rest in the series? Should it be edited, considering the particular date in question, at the risk of invalidating (and potentially intentionally deleting) some answers (that are off-topic anyway)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a little unilateral action:

- Edited the question to be clearly about the fast day (and therefore Judaism), which is consistent with the author's intent, as evidenced by the application of the fast-days tag. (And anyway, the question as originally posted was low-quality and not clearly on-topic, so editing is warranted.)
- Removed the jewish-date-series tag from this question, since that refers to a project that was neglected/rejected by the community.
- Deleted answers that don't have to do with the fast day.

Comment: Figured as much would happen. If it were about any random day on the calendar, I'd VTC (as I did for the rest of the series), but because of the reasons I mentioned in the OP, I thought such a course of action might be warranted in this case.

Comment: @DonielF Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Monica Maybe we [*should* nuke the tag entirely](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/)?

Comment: @DonielF I agree, but for that we need to go through the questions to make sure this wouldn't leave questions untagged.  This might mean deleting some questions and retagging others.  I didn't think Isaac had done all of that, but I looked to be sure and then made that small edit.